# PHP + SQL syntax varies from case to case, makes no sense

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

So I got this project I'm working on with PHP and Stripe. Everything is fine but I can't understand the logic behind the PHP syntax and how it changes.

As you see in the image the first update syntax ($sqlInsertEvent) has the syntax like this `:EventID='.$EventID.''`

But the other update didn't work with the exact same syntax, we had to use this instead : **ChargeID="'.$ChargeID.'"'**

Can someone explain to me why the heck there is two different syntax in the same code for the same function?

Comment: post the real code here not image

Comment: Please post the Code !

Comment: "Didn't work" ? Specify please

Comment: Edited update your code like this `Coupon = "TRUE"`. Thanks @modsfabio

Comment: @Nawin this won't work, he's using `'` for the query-string already

Comment: Maybe in the first case ```$EventID``` is a numeric value that why these is no QUOTE & in second case may be ```$ChargeID``` it's may be a CHAR/VARCHAR value that's why there is QUOTE used for wrapping it.

Answer (score 1):

`:EventID='.$EventID.''` means that the table field is numeric which doesn't require quotation marks.

`ChargeID="'.$ChargeID.'"'` means that the table field is varchar and requires quotations.

[MySql Varchar Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html)

Answer (score 0):

The concept is known as `concatenation of strings`. The two different cases used with mysql queries are:

```
1. 'SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE column = ' . $id;  // here column datatype is integer

2. "SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE column = '" . $id . "'";  // here column datatype is varchar or date or enum. So we have to wrap it in single quotes.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ChargeID is a string, so the quotes are needed when querying the column. The single quotes in both cases are to end the string for concatenation with the variable.

Although you can still use quotes to query an int!

Answer (score 0):

the first sql is

```
update xxx set xxx=xxx where EventId=123445;
```

the second sql is:

```
update xxx set xxx=xxx where ChargeId="kajfakjflajf";
```

first is integer and the other is string

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, the loop and the rest of the code works so RBT and others have the correct answer, I did not know that it was different syntax depending on varchar or int.

Thank you! Makes perfect sense now :)